# Excel Crashing when button with macro attached clicked

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that is attached to a button. However, when I test it in the VBA Editor, it runs fine. When the button is clicked with the macro attached it crashes excel. I have other macros attached which run fine.

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub rma_new()

Dim Sno As Long, LRow As Long, NewRow As Long
Dim wsO As Worksheet, wsI As Worksheet
Dim customeRef, customerName, customerCountry
Dim customerCompany, datePaid, dateShipped
Dim webInvoiceNumber, invoiceNumber, postCode
Dim assignedTo, salesChnl, orderValue

Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RMA")
Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1")

'~~> Get values from Sheet1
With wsI
    customeRef = .Range("c" & (ActiveCell.Row))
    customerName = .Range("d" & (ActiveCell.Row))
    customerCountry = .Range("e" & (ActiveCell.Row))
    customerCompany = .Range("f" & (ActiveCell.Row))
    datePaid = .Range("g" & (ActiveCell.Row))
    dateShipped = .Range("h" & (ActiveCell.Row))
    webInvoiceNumber = .Range("i" & (ActiveCell.Row))
    invoiceNumber = .Range("j" & (ActiveCell.Row))
    postCode = .Range("k" & (ActiveCell.Row))
    salesChnl = .Range("o" & (ActiveCell.Row))
    orderValue = .Range("a" & (ActiveCell.Row))


End With

'~~> Work with RMA Sheet
With wsO
    '~~> Get the last Row
    LRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    '~~> Increment the number
    Sno = .Range("A" & LRow).Value + 1
    '~~> New row where we need to write
    NewRow = LRow + 1

    .Cells(NewRow, 1) = Sno
    .Cells(NewRow, 2) = customeRef
    .Cells(NewRow, 3) = customerName
    .Cells(NewRow, 4) = customerCountry
    .Cells(NewRow, 5) = customerCompany
    .Cells(NewRow, 6) = datePaid
    .Cells(NewRow, 7) = dateShipped
    .Cells(NewRow, 8) = webInvoiceNumber
    .Cells(NewRow, 9) = invoiceNumber
    .Cells(NewRow, 10) = postCode
    .Cells(NewRow, 12) = salesChnl
    .Cells(NewRow, 14) = orderValue

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What error is it giving you?

Comment: No error, just crashing. How do I see an error if there is one?

Comment: You said "test it in the VBA editor," what exactly do you mean by that? Did you step through the `Sub` with no issues or simply compile your project without issues?

Comment: Just add the line `msgbox Activecell.address` after `Sub rma_new()`. What do you get?

Comment: It doesn't crash for me when running with blank sheets so it's probably related to the data in the cells. Any chance you can post a screenshot of example data?

Comment: Also, note that when you're saying `ActiveCell.Row` you're not qualifying a sheet.

Comment: In the VBA editor I click RUN @Dr.Trey

Comment: @user1274820 how do i qualify the sheet? Does it not do it with: Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1")

Comment: I just mean that it's the same as using `ActiveSheet.ActiveCell.Row`. it will return the row of whatever cell is selected for whichever sheet has the button. This may be as intended - I was just pointing it out.

Comment: I've been running it over and over with random data and I have had no issues with it crashing. (Excel 2010)

Comment: Its strange because it doesn't crash when I run it in the Editor, but when I assign it to a button it crashes every time! Im going to remove some of the code to see which part makes it crash.

Comment: Did you see my last message?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes, But I only got a cell reference of the cell selected!

Comment: Yup that is what it was supposed to do. Now do you know how to step through the code?

Comment: Wait.. did you get the cell address when you went via the button click or via the vba editor?

Comment: Yes, sort of. Do I just put that code after each line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89185/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-tbowden).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code and now my excel doesn't crash! I hope it helps.

```
Sub rma_New ()

    Dim LRow As Long, Sno As Long
    Dim myData As Workbook

    '--Get data from current sheet--
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Select
    orderValue = Range("a" & (ActiveCell.Row))
    customerRef = Range("c" & (ActiveCell.Row))
    customerName = Range("d" & (ActiveCell.Row))
    customerCountry = Range("e" & (ActiveCell.Row))

    '--Open Sheet 2--
    Worksheets("Sheet 2").Select

    '--Get value of previous cell in the row above in column A and add 1, inside Sheet 2--
    LRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sno = Range("A" & LRow).Value + 1

    '--Find the next empty row and append a new line with the data in the corresponding cells--
    Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("a8").Select
    RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("a8").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    With Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("a8")

  .Offset(RowCount, 0) = Sno
  .Offset(RowCount, 1) = customerRef
  .Offset(RowCount, 2) = customerName
  .Offset(RowCount, 3) = customerCountry

  End With

End Sub
```